# Where Is MySQL installed on My Machine?

Tags: debian, apt, mysql, administration

Recently I installed MySQL server on my Debian machine using Advanced Packaging Tool, and I'm curious to know where it's installed and how I can find all the source files and user databases.

I've only been able to find the configuration at `/etc/mysql`, and to find some other small pieces using `whereis` command and `find / -name "mysql"`, but besides that, nothing much exciting appears on screen.

Comment: What you want to do with the database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Debian versions of MySQL packages store the MySQL data in `/var/lib/mysql` directory by default. You can see this in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file also.

Debian packages don't contain any source code, if that is what you meant by source files. Binaries are installed generally in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` directories.

You can see where the package files are installed by using `dpkg -L <packagename>` command. Note the capital L letter.

If you want to know the packet name for MySQL, you can use `dpkg -l | grep mysql` to view all packages that have mysql in their names.

Comment: What about the "internal" database that comes with it (i.e. information_schema, mysql)? Where do I find those files?

Comment: The `mysql` database inside MySQL is stored in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` directory. `information_schema` is an internal table created by MySQL, and isn't actually stored anywhere.

Comment: What about password hashes, user information? Are they stored in plain text?

Comment: No, they are stored in the `mysql.user` table, located in the same data directory as other `mysql` dataabase tables.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in your path, try one of these:

```
which mysql
which mysqld
```

Edit: InnoDB is now the default engine, and to find its data files, assuming the installation was correctly done, view the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and look for the lines that contain `innodb_data_home_dir` and/or `innodb_data_file_path`.

Comment: This is only for the binaries, I want to search for the whole thing.

Comment: Answer edited: Try looking in the configuration file for the path.

Answer (score 0):

You have global configuration file - `/etc/myysql/my.cnf`. Other variables are inside mysql database that is (along with others), in the following location:
`/var/lib/mysql/`.

In fact, what you need is only binary mysql/mysqld/mysqladmin. If you really really wanted to see a whole list mysql server files, then:

1. assuming you haven't cleaned anything on this machine...
2. go to folder `/var/cache/apt/archives`
3. if you have midnight commander installed (mc packet), then run it and...
4. go to mentioned folder, search mysql-server file and press <kbd>F3</kbd>
5. This will show you server package content
6. Of course, there are also other packages (dependent) like `mysql-common` - look for strong Depends after <kbd>F3</kbd> pressed on selected package.